# Preventing Folders from being Deleted/Moved on a Share

Tags: windows-server-2003, file-sharing

Situation: Windows Server 2003 - Users all have a mapped network drive to a common "Shared Files" file share...

- File Share

  - Level 1 ("Projects" folder)

    - Level 2 (Files in the project folder)

Users have been accidentally moving Level 1 folders into other Level 2 folders. What's the magic combination of permissions to achieve the following:

- Users should be able to CREATE folders at Level 1.
- Users should have full control (create/modify/delete) at Level 2.
- Users should *not* be able to RENAME, DELETE, or MOVE folders at Level 1.

*Edit*: The trick here is that after a user creates a folder at level 2, they should automatically have full control at that level; any way to use "this level only' at Level 1 and achieve this?

Comment: Share and NTFS permissions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to create level one files, users need to have the Create permission for the file share folder. To prevent them from modifying level 1 folders, they need to be denied the modify permission on the file share folder.
User should then be given full control of the level 1 folder to allow them to create, edit and delete level 2 folders.

Hope that makes sense!